# Wcf data service projections and query methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I'm quite familiar with RIA Services, but not with WCF Data Services, and I'm wondering how to do something in the latter which I know how to do in the former.

I know examples for each data access methods on how to query database entities when the data service is backed by entity framework (or something similar).

But often enough I want to offer a queryable service method that isn't based on any database entity directly. It could be a combination from several database entities, an inherent grouping, or simply a database entity together with some additional, computed data.

Let's say I have the following classes:

```cs
// part of the model
class SomeEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String PropertyA { get; set; }
    public String PropertyB { get; set; }

    public Guid SubsidiaryKey { get; set; }
    public virtual SomeSubsidiaryEntity Subsidiary { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SomeRelatedEntity> RelatedEntities { get; set; }
}

// part of the model
class SomeSubsidiaryEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String PropertyS { get; set; }
}

// not part of the model, exists only for the service layer
class SomeEntityProjection
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String PropertyA { get; set; }
    public String PropertyB { get; set; }
    public String PropertyS { get; set; }
    public Int32 RelatedEntitiesCount { get; set; }
}
```

The first two are part of the database model the service is using, the last is a projection entity.

The projection entity isn't part of the database - it only exists in the service layer.

With RIA Services, I can now write a query function like this:

```cs
public IQueryable<SomeEntityProjection> GetSomeEntitiesWithSomeFluff()
{
    return
      from e in this.DbContext.SomeEntities
      select new SomeEntityProjection()
      {
        PropertyA = e.PropertyA,
        PropertyB = e.PropertyB,
        PropertyS = e.Subsidiary.PropertyS,
        RelatedEntitiesCount = e.RelatedEntities.Count()
      }
}
```

The data service method then supports client-side filtering and sorting for all four properties. All such client-side sorting and filtering will be properly delegated to the database and done there.

I couldn't find any examples of this for WCF Data Services, so my question is: Is this possible with WCF Data Services also and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You would use [Data Transfer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx) (DTO) across the wire, which are similar, but not necessarily identical to your entity objects. That way they can vary independently.

Comment: You could say that SomeEntityProjection in my example is such a DTO. That still leaves the question how to actually do it with WCF Data Service.